# Why the HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String happened in save arraylist to SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I try to use the following code to set and get the ArrayList to/from `SharedPreferences`. But it show the following error when I call `getSharedPreferencesMutableList`:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
com.bbin.authenticator.Support.sharedPreference.SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferencesMutableList
```

The code is like the following:

```
fun setSharedPreferencesMutableList(context: Context, setName: String, value: ArrayList<String>) {
    var gson = Gson()
    var json = gson.toJson(value)

    val setting = context.getSharedPreferences(UBAuth, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    setting.edit().putString(setName, json).apply()

}

fun getSharedPreferencesMutableList(context: Context, getName: String): ArrayList<String> {
    val setting = context.getSharedPreferences(UBAuth, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var json = setting.getString(getName,"")
    var type = object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type
    var list = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<String>>(json, type)

    if(list != null){
        return list
    }else{
        return ArrayList<String>()
    }
}
```

I did not set anything to `SharedPreferences` for calling `setSharedPreferencesMutableList`. So the value is empty.

Why it show this error?
Did I missing something ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is you have a Shared Preferences with a key that is not a String.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says that in this case a `ClassCastException` is thrown